# IIS url rewrite - lowercase outbound rule condition for flash object/param urls

Tags: .net, iis, url-rewriting

I have a.net 4.0 project and am using  IIS 7.5 url rewrite rules to enforce lowercase on all urls - both inbound and outbound rules. I have everything functional as desired but for the case of an object param tag value being lowered:

```
    <object width="600" height="378" id="flash_258112502" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/_resources/flash/videoplayer.swf">  
    <param value="rtmp://media.website.org/vod/mp4:20110302councilmeeting.f4v" name="serverurl"> 
</object>
```

These urls for the flash server are indeed case sensitive and so modifying their case breaks functionality. How does one write a targeted condition to exclude these urls from being re-written?

My web.config re-write outbound rules are as follows, i have tried to add custom tags to be able to match /object or param but to no avail:

```
 <outboundRules rewriteBeforeCache="true">
    <!-- convert all links to lowercase -->
    <rule name="Outbound lowercase" preCondition="IsHTML" enabled="true">
      <match filterByTags="A, Script, CustomTags" customTags="object" pattern=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{ToLower:{R:0}}" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="/workarea/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="media.website.org" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^.*\.(ashx|axd|css|gif|png|js|flv|f4v)$" negate="true" /> 
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <!-- Only process html files -->
      <preCondition name="IsHTML" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
            <customTags>
                <tags name="param">
                    <tag name="param" attribute="param" />
                </tags>
                <tags name="object" />
            </customTags>
  </outboundRules>
```

-my first stackoverflow post , please and thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The rule should not contain object as you don't want it to match and get lowercased

```
<match filterByTags="A, Script" pattern=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false" />
```

Start with this

```
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Outbound LowerCase Rule">
            <match filterByTags="A" pattern=".*[A-Z].*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="{ToLower:{R:0}}" />
        </rule>
    </outboundRules>
```

Comment: Removing the object tag as specified doesn't prevent the lowercasing.  'Object' ended up there in attempt to ensure that we're actually processing that tag to be able to create a condition to negate the lowercase rule. I'm not sure what is actually converting because i have declared the path "media.website.org"  and the extension ".f4v" as rule negators.

Comment: I did a simpler test to verify and it works as expected. I would break it down to simplest possible rule (e.g. just inlcude A, Script) and start from there. Add more rules (including the negate) one at a time.

Comment: no luck. i'm about all tried out - i've tried every idea and combo that i can imagine.

Comment: Start with just one rule. What does that do?